# How do I make a Tor HSP on IIS / ASP.NET Core?

Tags: onion-services, windows

I want to run ASP.NET Core on a non Windows machine with Tor.

How can I configure IIS / ASP.NET Core to publish an HSP endpoint?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking correctly, then you don't. You point Tor's `HiddenServicePort` at the httpd and Tor handles setting up and publishing the onion service.

Comment: @canonizingironize Got it. Thanks.  Will try that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your chosen httpd to listen on `127.0.0.1:80` (the port can be arbitrary, just update the value in the torrc to match).

Then download a copy of the [Tor Expert Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en), extract it into a folder on your Desktop or similar, e.g. `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Tor\`

Create a flat text file with contents like:

```
SocksPort 0 # we don't need SOCKS, we're not a client
DataDirectory "C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop\\Tor\\Data" # I think this should be reasonable for a Windows users Tor data?
HiddenServiceDir "C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop\\Tor\\Data\\onion"
HiddenServicePort 80 80 # points port 80 on the onion to a service running on 127.0.0.1:80
Log notice file "C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop\\Tor\\Data\\notice.log"
```

Save the file to somewhere like `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Tor\torrc`

Now open up cmd.exe and nagivate to `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Tor\Tor` and launch `tor.exe` with a command line `tor.exe -f C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Tor\torrc`. If I recall correctly, `tor.exe` has issues with printing output to the Windows terminal (`cmd.exe`) so check the file set as the log above, and ensure that everything looks okay.

If all went well, you'll now have a file at `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Tor\Data\onion\hostname` which will contain the .onion address generated. Give it a minute or so to publish then try to visit the address in the file, and it should connect to your httpd.

*(Given your previous question about scallion, you can stop `tor.exe` then replace the content of the `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Tor\Data\onion\private_key` with one of the generated keys, then start tor and it should publish for the custom onion hostname.)*